# ExtJS 4 empty space on panel in tab

Tags: layout, extjs4

I can't make grid on panel flexible. The situation is the following:

```
------------------------
| tab1 | tab 2 | tab 3 |
|      ------------------------------
|-----------------------------------|
|  form                             |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |  
|-----------------------------------|
|  gridpanel                        |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|-----------------------------------|
|  toolbar                          | 
|-----------------------------------|
|                                   |
|          ???                      |
|                                   |
-------------------------------------
```

This is panel (in fact tabpanel) with three elements on it: form, grid and toolbar. Form height is flexible (sometimes I display more fields then in standard case), and I want to have gridpanel height also flexible to fill accessible place between form and toolbar (tolbar high is constat).
I removed all "height" values and set gridpanel layout to 'fit". No result and I still have this "???" area empty.
Be so kind as to prompt me how to solve this.

Ok, here you are:

```
 {
      xtype: 'panel',
       title: 'Serwis',
      items: [
          {
              xtype:     'form',
              itemId:    'FRM_SERWIS',
              bodyStyle: 'background-color: #DFE8F6',
              border:    false,
              defaults:  {
                  readOnly:       true,
                  labelSeparator: '',
                  labelWidth:     200,
                  fieldStyle:     'background:none;border: none;',
                  labelStyle:     'font-weight:bold;'
              },
              items: [
                  {
                      xtype:      'textfield',
                      fieldLabel: 'Name:',
                      margin:     '20, 0, 5, 50',
                      value:      frm_name,
                      width:      500
                  },

                  ...

                  {
                      xtype:      'textarea',
                      fieldLabel: 'Warning:',
                      margin:     '0, 0, 5, 50',
                      value:      frm_war,
                      width:      500
                  }
              ]
          },
          {
              xtype:      'gridpanel',
              store:      'FrmStore',
              // height:     240,
              layout:     'fit',
              border:     true,
              columns:    [
                  {
                      xtype:    'gridcolumn',
                      style:    'text-align:center;font-weight: bold;color:#000000;',
                      flex:      2,
                      align:     'left',
                      text:      'Data'
                  },
                  {
                      xtype:     'gridcolumn',
                      style:     'text-align:center;font-weight: bold;color:#000000;',
                      flex:      1,
                      align:     'left',
                      text:      'Invoice no'
                  },
                  {
                      xtype:     'gridcolumn',
                      style:     'text-align:center;font-weight: bold;color:#000000;',
                      flex:      1,
                      align:     'center',
                      text:      'Value'
                  }
              ]
          }
      ],
      dockedItems: [
          {
              xtype: 'toolbar',
              dock: 'bottom',
              height: 30,
              items: [
                  {
                      xtype:   'button',
                      cls:     'cap-btn',
                      text:    'Action',
                      handler: me.onAction,
                      margin:  '0 0 0 10'
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
  },
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: You know, reset all settings in browser was for nothing. But next day I found code above is working. Don't know why ;_)